# JavaScript product new Menu

Tags: javascript

i wanna product new menu i try Recursive dictionary array
but still not get correct datas.

below its two array , globalRoutes its dict array , menuRoutes its normal array i wanna use

menuRoutes to search globalRoutes

below its my code:

```
const globalRoutes = [
    {
        path: '/user',
        meta: {
            title: 'UserManager',
            icon: 'el-icon-user'
        },
        children: [{
            path: 'userinfo',
            meta: {
                title: 'UserInfo',
            }
        },
        {
            path: 'roleinfo',
            meta: {
                title: 'Roleinfo'
            }
        },
        {
            path: 'rolemenu',
            meta: {
                title: 'roleMenu'
            }
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '/test',
        meta: {
            title: 'TestMenu',
            icon: 'el-icon-setting'
        }
    }
]


const menuRoutes = ['userinfo', '/test']

function Test1(routes) {
    res = []
    for(let route of routes){
        console.log(route.path)
        const data = {}
        let menuIndex = menuRoutes.indexOf(route.path)
        if(menuIndex > -1){
            data.path = route.path
            data.meta = route.meta
        }else{
            if(route.children){
                data.path = route.path
                data.meta = route.meta
                data.children = Test1(route.children)
            }
        }
        if (Object.keys(data).length > 0){
            res.push(data)
        }

    }
    return res
}

console.log(Test1(globalRoutes))
```

Error datas as below:

```
[
  { path: 'userinfo', meta: { title: 'UserInfo' } },
  {
    path: '/user',
    meta: { title: 'UserManager', icon: 'el-icon-user' },
    children: [Circular]
  },
  {
    path: '/test',
    meta: { title: 'TestMenu', icon: 'el-icon-setting' }
  }
]
```

I wanted correct data as below:

```
[

  {
    path: '/user',
    meta: { title: 'UserManager', icon: 'el-icon-user' },
    children: [{ path: 'userinfo', meta: { title: 'UserInfo' } }]
  },
  {
    path: '/test',
    meta: { title: 'TestMenu', icon: 'el-icon-setting' }
  }
]
```

how need i change code to get correct datas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example based on your code.

```js
const globalRoutes = [
    {
        path: '/user',
        meta: {
            title: 'UserManager',
            icon: 'el-icon-user'
        },
        children: [{
            path: 'userinfo',
            meta: {
                title: 'UserInfo',
            }
        },
        {
            path: 'roleinfo',
            meta: {
                title: 'Roleinfo'
            }
        },
        {
            path: 'rolemenu',
            meta: {
                title: 'roleMenu'
            }
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '/test',
        meta: {
            title: 'TestMenu',
            icon: 'el-icon-setting'
        }
    }
];

const menuRoutes = ['userinfo', '/test'];

const inRoutes = (search, routes) => {
    let result = [];

    routes.forEach((item, index) => {
        if (search.includes(item.path)) {
            result.push(item);
        }

        if (item.children) {
            item.children.forEach((itm, idx) => {
                if (search.includes(itm.path)) {
                    item.children = item.children.filter(i => i === itm); // or item.children = [itm];
                    result.push(item);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    
    return result;
};

console.log(inRoutes(menuRoutes, globalRoutes));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi N'Bayramberdiyev thanks for you comment , i try you example , all children include

Comment: thanks a lot how can i get score to u , its really good Answer

Comment: sorry i take some minutes not found where to mark accepted , i will find it share score to you .